# color active navbar when selected

Tags: php, html, css

In my navigation bar that I am building, the hover is working fine. But when I click a button, the blue color on the font stays on "hjem". At the moment "hjem" call a class called "active". I am not quite sure if I can solve that with CSS, or I have to make some JavaScript for that?

At the moment my HTML header looks like this:

```
<!-- header-container start -->
            <div class="header-container">
                <header class="header  fixed    clearfix">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 ">
                                <!-- header-left start -->
                                <!-- ================ -->
                                <div class="header-left clearfix">

                                    <!-- header dropdown buttons -->
                                    <div class="header-dropdown-buttons visible-xs">
                                        <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-animation">
                                                <li>
                                                    <form role="search" class="search-box margin-clear">
                                                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                                            <i class="icon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- header dropdown buttons end-->

                                    <!-- logo -->
                                    <div id="logo" class="logo">
                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/index.php"><img id="logo_img" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/images/graphics/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!-- header-left end -->

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="main-navigation  animated with-dropdown-buttons">

                                    <!-- navbar start -->
                                    <!-- ================ -->
                                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">

                                            <!-- Toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                </button>

                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                                                <!-- main-menu -->
                                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">

                                                    <!-- mega-menu start -->
                                                    <li class="active mega-menu">
                                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/index.php">Hjem</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <!-- mega-menu end -->

                                                    <!-- mega-menu start -->

                                                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu">
                                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kompetencer</a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">

                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                                <h4 class="title">Design</h4>
                                                                                <div class="divider"></div>
                                                                                <ul class="menu">
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/ux-ui.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>UX/UI</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/prototyping.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Prototyping</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/web-design.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Web Design</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/grafisk-design.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Grafisk Design</a></li>
                                                                                </ul>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                                <h4 class="title">Webudvikling</h4>
                                                                                <div class="divider"></div>
                                                                                <ul class="menu">
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/webudvikling.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Webudvikling</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/php-mysql.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>PHP & MySQL databaser</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/wordpress.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Wordpress</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/umbraco.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Umbraco</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/joomla.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Joomla</a></li>
                                                                                </ul>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                                <h4 class="title">Marketing Automation</h4>
                                                                                <div class="divider"></div>
                                                                                <ul class="menu">
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/mautic.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Mautic</a></li>
                                                                                    <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/landeside.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Landesider</a></li>
                                                                                </ul>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
                                                                        <h4 class="title">Oversigt over kompetencer</h4>
                                                                        <p class="mb-10"><a href=" http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kompetencer/alle-kompetencer.php"><u>En oversigt over alle mine kompetencer</u></a></p>
                                                                        <img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/images/graphics/kompetencer.png" alt="The Project">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu">
                                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <!-- mega-menu end -->
                                                    <li class="dropdown ">
                                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profil</a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                            <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/uddannelse.php">Uddannelse</a></li>
                                                            <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/erhvervserfaring.php">Erhvervserfaring</a></li>
                                                            <li ><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/personlighed.php">Personlighed</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="mega-menu">
                                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/artikler-index.php">Artikler</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <!-- mega-menu start -->
                                                    <!-- mega-menu start -->
                                                    <li class="mega-menu">
                                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
                                                    </li>


                                                </ul>
                                                <!-- main-menu end -->

                                                <!-- header dropdown buttons -->
                                                <div class="header-dropdown-buttons hidden-xs ">
                                                    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-animation">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <form role="search" class="search-box margin-clear">
                                                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                                                        <i class="icon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </form>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- header dropdown buttons end-->

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </nav>
                                    <!-- navbar end -->

                                </div>
                                <!-- main-navigation end -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- header-right end -->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </header>
                <!-- header end -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you just have to change your active class with your page.

```
    function set_active($path){
    $a= explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $page = array_pop($a);

    if ($page == $path.'.php'){
        return "active";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}


<li class="<?= set_active('profile'); ?>">
```

Well i'm trying to help, i'm not really good, but when i want to put my menu active I do this function. Good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay It was not so hard as I thought at all.

**HTML**

```
<body id="portfolio">
 <a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
```

**navbar.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("#portfolio a:contains('Portfolio')").parent().addClass('active');
});
```